# Listen to All Emitted Events in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, events, node.js

In Node.js is there any way to listen to *all* events emitted by an EventEmitter object?

e.g., can you do something like...

```
event_emitter.on('',function(event[, arg1][, arg2]...) {}
```

The idea is that I want to grab all of the events spit out by a server side `EventEmitter`, `JSON.stringify` the event data, send it across a websockets connection, reform them on the client side as an event, and then act on the event on the client side.

Comment: The _events attribute seems to depend on the listeners that are defined on the object, so it does not do what the question asks. In other words, if one defines a listener e.on("foo",...), then "foo" shows up in e._events, even if e never actually emits "foo". On the other hand, e might emit "bar", which, if not listened to, will not show up in e._events. For debugging, in particular, it would be nice to have such a "wildcard" capability, a listener of the form e.on("*",...), but this feature does not seem to be available.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As mentioned this behavior is not in node.js core. But you can use hij1nx's EventEmitter2:

https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2

It won't break any existing code using EventEmitter, but adds support for namespaces and wildcards. For example:

```
server.on('foo.*', function(value1, value2) {
  console.log(this.event, value1, value2);
});
```

Comment: It also has a `emitter.onAny(listener)` method which adds a listener that will be fired when any event is emitted.

Comment: This won't help with any existing internal uses of the node.js baked in event emitter though which is what the asker is looking for. I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/18087021/455556 answers the question perfectly

Comment: @SalmanPK How does `onAny` pass event names? Because I tried `obj.onAny(function() {console.log(arguments);});` and I only got event parameters without names...

Answer (score 91):

I know this is a bit old, but what the hell, here is another solution you could take.

You can easily monkey-patch the emit function of the emitter you want to catch all events:

```
function patchEmitter(emitter, websocket) {
  var oldEmit = emitter.emit;

  emitter.emit = function() {
      var emitArgs = arguments;
      // serialize arguments in some way.
      ...
      // send them through the websocket received as a parameter
      ...
      oldEmit.apply(emitter, arguments);
  }
}
```

This is pretty simple code and should work on any emitter.

Comment: Used this method with mail-listener2 to avoid having to subscribe to all events just to log them, this is simpler for my tiny task.

Comment: As used by [substack](https://github.com/substack/emit-stream/blob/b62e7f2361944bdf6b194843830e0903879aa9f2/index.js#L28).

Comment: I preferred this method too. No extra deps and works rather well for logging purposes as @yzorg said. Thanks.

Comment: suggest to change line oldEmit.apply(emitter, arguments); to return oldEmit.apply(emitter, arguments);

Answer (score 25):

With ES6 classes it's very easy:

```js
class Emitter extends require('events') {
    emit(type, ...args) {
        console.log(type + " emitted")
        super.emit(type, ...args)
    }
}
```

Comment: can this be done an an existing instance of EventEmitter that someone else created?

Comment: with this approach you cannot, but you can patch `instance.prototype.emit` function

Answer (score 13):

Be aware that all solutions described above will involve some sort of hacking around node.js EventEmitter internal implementation.

The right answer to this question would be: **the default EventEmitter implementation does not support that, you need to hack around it**.

If you take a look on node.js source code for EventEmitter, you can see listeners are retrieved from a hash using event type as a key, and it will just return without any further action if the key is not found:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/98819dfa5853d7c8355d70aa1aa7783677c391e5/lib/events.js#L176-L179

That's why something like `eventEmitter.on('*', ()=>...)` can't work by default.

Answer (score 9):

Since Node.js v6.0.0, the new `class` syntax and argument spread operator is fully supported, so it's pretty safe and fairly easy to implement the desired functionality with simple inheritance and an method override:

```
'use strict';
var EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  emit(type, ...args) {
    super.emit('*', ...args);
    return super.emit(type, ...args) || super.emit('', ...args);
  }
}
```

This implementation relies on the fact that the original `emit` method of the `EventEmitter` returns `true`/`false` depending if the event was handled by some listener or not. Notice that the override includes a `return` statement, so we keep this behavior for other consumers.

Here the idea is to use the star event (`*`) to create handlers that gets executed on every single event (say, for logging purposes) and the empty event (`''`) for a default or catch all handler, that gets executed if nothing else catches that event.

We make sure to call the star (`*`) event first, because in case of `error` events without any handlers, the result is actually an exception being thrown. For more details, take a look at the [implementation of the `EventEmitter`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L146-L206).

For example:

```
var emitter = new MyEmitter();

emitter.on('foo', () => console.log('foo event triggered'));
emitter.on('*', () => console.log('star event triggered'));
emitter.on('', () => console.log('catch all event triggered'));

emitter.emit('foo');
    // Prints:
    //   star event triggered
    //   foo event triggered

emitter.emit('bar');
    // Prints:
    //   star event triggered
    //   catch all event triggered
```

Finally, if an EventEmitter instance already exists but you want to adjust that specific instance to the new behavior, it can be easily done by patching the method at runtime like this:

```
emitter.emit = MyEmitter.prototype.emit;
```

Comment: This is a clever idea. Kudos

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the answer that Martin provided above.  I'm a bit new to node, so I needed to work out his answer for myself.  The method at the end, logAllEmitterEvents is the important bit.

```
var events = require('events');
var hungryAnimalEventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function emitHungryAnimalEvents()
{
    hungryAnimalEventEmitter.emit("HungryCat");
    hungryAnimalEventEmitter.emit("HungryDog");
    hungryAnimalEventEmitter.emit("Fed");
}

var meow = function meow()
{
  console.log('meow meow meow');
}

hungryAnimalEventEmitter.on('HungryCat', meow);

logAllEmitterEvents(hungryAnimalEventEmitter);

emitHungryAnimalEvents();

function logAllEmitterEvents(eventEmitter)
{
    var emitToLog = eventEmitter.emit;

    eventEmitter.emit = function () {
        var event = arguments[0];
        console.log("event emitted: " + event);
        emitToLog.apply(eventEmitter, arguments);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to trace all emitted events in all libraries, so I tapped into the `prototype`.

This example uses a `Typescript signature`, but you can just remove it if you are not into that kind of nonsense.

Within the call, `this` refers to the object that is emitting. It was very easy to track all unique object:emits in my project.

```
  // For my example I use a `set` to track unique emits.
  const items = new Set()

  const originalEmit = EventEmitter.prototype.emit;
  EventEmitter.prototype.emit = function (event: String | Symbol, ...args: any[]): boolean {

    // Do what you want here
    const id = this.constructor.name + ":" + event;
    if (!items.has(id)) {
      items.add(id);
      console.log(id);
    }

    // And then call the original
    return originalEmit.call(event, ...args);
  }
```

You can very easily extend this and filter based on event name or class name.

Answer (score 1):

a monkey patch add onAny method to EventEmitter.

it is useful to be able to monitor only events of one problem.

```
var EventEmitter=require('events')
var origemit=EventEmitter.prototype.emit;
Object.assign( EventEmitter.prototype, {
  emit:function(){
    if(this._onAnyListeners){
        this._onAnyListeners.forEach((listener)=>listener.apply(this,arguments))
    }
    return origemit.apply(this,arguments)
  },
  onAny:function(func){
    if(typeof func !== 'function'){
      throw new Error('Invalid type');
    }
    if(!this._onAnyListeners)this._onAnyListeners=[];
    this._onAnyListeners.push(func);
  },
  removeOnAny:function(func){
    const index = this._onAnyListeners.indexOf(func);
    if(index === -1){
      return;
    }
    this._onAnyListeners.splice(index,1);
  }
});
// usage example
//gzip.onAny(function(a){console.log(a)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into RPC modules for node.js. If I am not mistaken the Dnode RPC module has an [chat server/client example](https://github.com/substack/dnode/tree/master/examples/chat) similar to what you are trying to do. So you could either make use of their module or copy what they are doing.

In brief the example shows a server which on connection creates listeners for all the server events from the connected client. It does this by simply iterating over a stored list of event names.

```
var evNames = [ 'joined', 'said', 'parted' ];

con.on('ready', function () {
    evNames.forEach(function (name) {
        emitter.on(name, client[name]);
    });
    emitter.emit('joined', client.name);
});
```

This code is clever because it automatically calls a remote procedure call on the client associated with the event when the event is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem today, heres a solution:

```
Object.create(Object.assign({},EventEmitter.prototype, {
  _onAnyListeners:[],
  emit:function(...args){
    //Emit event on every other server

    if(this._fireOnAny && typeof this._fireOnAny === 'function'){
      this._fireOnAny.apply(this,args)
    }

    EventEmitter.prototype.emit.apply(this,args)
  },
  _fireOnAny:function(...args){
    this._onAnyListeners.forEach((listener)=>listener.apply(this,args))
  },
  onAny:function(func){
    if(typeof func !== 'function'){
      throw new Error('Invalid type');
    }
    this._onAnyListeners.push(func);
  },
  removeOnAny:function(func){
    const index = this._onAnyListeners.indexOf(func);
    if(index === -1){
      return;
    }
    this._onAnyListeners.splice(index,1);
  }
}));
```

Comment: If you can't create the EventEmitter yourself, you will have to assign directly to the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of extending Events class using a function rather than es6 class as describes by @pravdomil

```
const Events = require('events');

 
 function Emitter(){
   Object.assign(this, Events.prototype)

   let emit = this.emit;
   this.emit = (type, ...args) => {
      console.log('type', type);
      emit.call(this, type, ...args);
   }
   return this;
}

const eventEmitter = new Emitter();

function shout(a){
   console.log(`${a}`);
}
eventEmitter.on('shout', shout)

eventEmitter.emit('shout', 'stack overflow');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Typescript implementation. I tried to get proper typing internally, but externally it works:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

type EventMap<T> = Record<keyof T, any[]> | DefaultEventMap;
type DefaultEventMap = [never];

export class WildcardEventEmitter<T extends EventMap<T> = DefaultEventMap> extends EventEmitter<T> {
  
  emit<K>(eventName: T extends [never] ? string | symbol : keyof T | K, ...args: T extends [never] ? any[] : K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never): boolean {
    //@ts-expect-error
    super.emit('*', eventName, ...args);
    return super.emit(eventName, ...args);// || super.emit('', ...args);
  }

  //@ts-expect-error
  on(eventName: '*', listener: (eventName: keyof T, ...args: any[]) => void): this;
  //@ts-expect-error
  on<K>(eventName: T extends [never] ? string | symbol : (keyof T) | K, listener: T extends [never] ? (...args: any[]) => void : K extends keyof T ? T[K] extends unknown[] ? (...args: T[K]) => void : never : never): this {
    if(eventName === '*')
    //@ts-expect-error
      return super.on('*', ()=>listener(eventName, ...args))
    return super.on(eventName, listener);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a debug tool inspired by Martin's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18087021/1264797).  I just now used this to figure out what was going wrong in a set of streams by logging all of their events to the console.  Works great.  As Martin illustrates, OP could use it by replacing the console.log() call with a websocket sender.

```
function debug_emitter(emitter, name) {
    var orig_emit = emitter.emit;
    emitter.emit = function() {
        var emitArgs = arguments;
        console.log("emitter " + name + " " + util.inspect(emitArgs));
        orig_emit.apply(emitter, arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you are missing `var util = require('util');`

Answer (score -3):

You can also use another event emitter implementation like https://github.com/ozantunca/DispatcherJS. The implementation would be like:

```
dispatcher.on('*', function () {});
```

DispatcherJS also supports namespaces and even dependencies to determine which callbacks are going to be called first.