# How to listen all action in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a nodejs event which is listening all action sent by nodejs **without modifying the lib source**.

For example, i've got 2 actions :

```
socket.on("login", function() { //do something });
socket.on("getUser", function() { //do something });
```

But if socket sent me an action except "login" or "getUser", i'd like to do something like this :

```
socket.on("actionUnknow", function() { socket.disconnect(); });
```

I've found some topics on stackoverflow with the same problem, but answers was to modify lib source and I don't want to do it.

Comment: The default implementation of events doesn't support that http://stackoverflow.com/a/10018819/941764

Comment: @OrangeDog It's not a duplicate. The answer to the question you linked to suggests using a different EventEmitter implementation, which would mean changing the source code.

Answer (score 2):

The EventEmitter implementation used by node.js does not support wildcards of any kind, so basically you are out of luck. You could monkey-patch `socket.emit`, but that's more of a hack than anything:

```
var origEmit = socket.emit;
socket.emit = function(ev) {
  console.log(ev);
  origEmit.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Comment: Nop, i don't want to do that. I'd like to know if it can be dangerous for node server if "socket" spamming unknow node event ?