# Forwarding events from one event emitter to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I have one event emitter (a transform stream) and that event emitter basically has a bunch of child emitters.

I want to forward events from all the child emitters to the parent emitter, something like this:

```
const EE = require('events');
const exportEvents = new EE();

const sumanEvents = Transform();     // create new transform stream (an event emitter)

sumanEvents.on('test', function () {
  exportEvents.emit.bind(exportEvents, 'test').apply(exportEvents, arguments);
});

sumanEvents.on('error', function () {
  exportEvents.emit.bind(exportEvents, 'error').apply(exportEvents, arguments);
});

sumanEvents.on('suman-test-file-complete', function () {
  exportEvents.emit.bind(exportEvents, 'suman-test-file-complete').apply(exportEvents, arguments);
});
```

Basically, from what I can tell, I have forwarded the error, test, and suman-test-file-complete events to the parent, but this seems pretty ugly.

Is there at least a more sophisticated way of doing it? I assume there is not a way to directly inherit events with Node.js 'events' package so I am not asking about that.

Answer (score 3):

You could override `sumanEvents.emit()` so you could see any event that was emitted and then grab it and echo it to `exportEvents`:

```
(function(origEmitter, forwardEmitter) {
    // save original .emit method
    let oldEmit = origEmitter.emit;

    // assign override
    origEmitter.emit = function() {
        // allow the event to be normally emitted
        oldEmit.apply(origEmitter, arguments);

        // then forward it to the forwardEmitter
        forwardEmitter.emit.apply(forwardEmitter, arguments);
    };
})(sumanEvents, exportEvents);
```

Or, put into a reusable function form so you can use it on more than one emitter without copying the code:

```
function forwardEmitter(origEmitter, forwardEmitter) {
    // save original .emit method
    let oldEmit = origEmitter.emit;

    // assign override
    origEmitter.emit = function() {
        // allow the event to be normally emitted
        oldEmit.apply(origEmitter, arguments);

        // then forward it to the forwardEmitter
        forwardEmitter.emit.apply(forwardEmitter, arguments);
    };
}

forwardEmitter(sumanEvents, exportEvents);
```

---

This functionality could be encapsulated in a new object that derives from `EventEmitter` if you wanted to more easily be able to reuse it, but that would only work if you control the creation of the first EventEmitter object so you could make it your special derived object that supported forwarding of all messages.  The example above can be "added on" to any existing regular `EventEmitter` object.

---

There's also an `EventEmitter2` object [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178869/listen-to-all-emitted-events-in-node-js) that allows you to use wildcards to register event handlers so you could register an interest in all events or a subset of events that way without naming each one individually.

---

And, there's a discussion of this concept on a Google mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs-dev/TzRPxsHf0FA

Comment: thanks, the first solution won't work easily for me, because I have multiple sumanEvents emitters, not just one, and I don't have a handle on all of those different sumanEvents emitters at the time that exportEvents is declared, if that makes sense, but your second solution might work for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> but this seems pretty ugly.

Is there a reason you're binding and applying? It seems like these are being used incorrectly. Lines like `exportEvents.emit.bind(exportEvents, 'test').apply(exportEvents, arguments)` can be simplified to `EE.emit.apply(exportEvents, 'test', arguments)` or, using spread syntax, `exportEvents.emit('test', ...arguments)`

That being said, a utility function might be helpful here. [jfriend00's above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40856206/675721) is ok, but I don't really like that it overrides a method on the original object (even if the original method is being called).

The other solution actually works out to be simpler (fewer lines of code):

```
function forwardEvent(emitterToListenOn, emitterToEmitOn, event) {
  emitterToListenOn.on(event, function() { //can't use arrow here, as we need 'arguments'
    emitterToEmitOn.emit(event, arguments);
  });
}

function forwardEvents(emitterToListenOn, emitterToEmitOn, events) {
  events.forEach(event => forwardEvent(emitterToListenOn, emitterToEmitOn, event));
}

function forwardEventsToMultipleEmitters(emitterToListenOn, emittersToEmitOn, events) {
  emittersToEmitOn.forEach(emitterToEmitOn => forwardEvents(emitterToListenOn, emitterToEmitOn, events));
}
```

For those that aren't comfortable with arrow functions, here's the same code without:

```js
function forwardEvent(emitterToListenOn, emitterToEmitOn, event) {
  emitterToListenOn.on(event, function() { //can't use arrow here, as we need 'arguments'
emitterToEmitOn.emit(event, arguments);
  });
}

function forwardEvents(emitterToListenOn, emitterToEmitOn, events) {
  events.forEach(function(event) {
forwardEvent(emitterToListenOn, emitterToEmitOn, event);
  });
}

function forwardEventsToMultipleEmitters(emitterToListenOn, emittersToEmitOn, events) {
  emittersToEmitOn.forEach(function(emitterToEmitOn) {
forwardEvents(emitterToListenOn, emitterToEmitOn, events);
  });
}
```

To use these in your original code,

```
const EE = require('events');
const exportEvents = new EE();

const sumanEvents = Transform();     // create new transform stream (an event emitter)
forwardEvents(sumanEvents, exportEvents, ['test', 'error', 'suman-test-file-complete']);
```

This `forwardEvent` is fewer lines of code than jfriend00's `forwardEmitter` and doesn't override any functions and the final solution looks pretty clean to me.